# PHP error 500 sending mail

Tags: php, smtp, server, iis-6

I'm having a problem here I hope you can help with, I've got a web server using iis6 and php, php config is setup to use my sbs2008 SMTP server to send email.

My problem is that about 7 times out of 10 the email fails but sometimes it works fine. I've actually got owncloud setup but when it comes to sending an email its very intermittent.

I know this is nothing to do with Owncloud as ive got a small php mail test script that just sends emails - cloud.codeman.org/mailtest.php but you will see sometime i get 500 error and sometimes test email sent, driving me crazy  :-x

I wonder if there's a way to diagnose what's happening or if someone has seen this before.

Cheers
Mark

PS im using Windows 7 IIS6 with PHP and sending mail to SBS2008 using SMTP to pass to my website host to get the mail to the outside world.

Answer (score -1):

You should check your error log, when you get the "Internal Server Error", usually error log points you in the right direction.

If you don't know its path, see
[Where does PHP store the error log? (php5, apache, fastcgi, cpanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log)

AND 

wrap the mail function in an if block to see if it was executed successfully.

```
if(!mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)){
  echo error_get_last();
}
```

Comment: CHECK THE ERROR LOG AND PASTE IT HERE, after removing sensitive information of course.

Comment: Ill give that a try and get back